# ASP.NET MVC - Dynamically load multiple partial view in same bootstrap modal popup

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have to dynamically load partial view content in same Modal Popup.

1. once the modal popup is open then partial view-1 content will be loaded.
2. In that partial view there is another button to invoke other partial view but here I have to load other partial view in same modal popup. modal popup content should be refreshed.here I don't want popup in popup

currently what I was doing this-->

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EmployeeModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">New Employee</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/Details1_Partial.cshtml", Model.Employee)
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but I have to load another partial view in same popup with button click action available in first view. here I don't want popup in popup (showing two popup). existing modal popup content should get refreshed.

here Details1_Partial.cshtml has button to invoke another popup. but that partial view should use the same modal pop up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create additional controller method, returning another view or receiving additional parameter to select necessary view. Then add handler on the button click event to sent AJAX request to the controller method and refresh the modal with response content.

Comment: Alternatively to what @Alexander wrote, you could load both partial views in your modal, where one is hidden, and on button click you show that one, and hide the initially shown.